# Sharing multiple images AND text using activityController is not working

Tags: swift, xcode, email, share

I am making a sales app to email charts as images with text for my company, but I am having a problem with my app.

For some reason I can't send multiple images and text together, when the code below is activated, only the text is sent.

I triple checked and the images are NOT nil and I can share text, multiple images alone or text and a single image just fine.

Furthermore I am only sending two images and this is just for the phone version alone.

```
func EmailMultipleImages(imageArray: [UIImage], emailSubject: String, emailBodyText : String) {
    

    print("Image array \(imageArray.count)")
    do {
        let shareContent: [Any] = [imageArray, emailBodyText]
        
        //Multiple images alone
        //let shareContent: [Any] = [imageArray]
        
        //Text alone
        //let shareContent: [Any] = [emailBodyText]
        
        //One image and text
        //let shareContent: [Any] = [imageArray[0], emailBodyText]
       
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareContent, applicationActivities: nil)

        activityController.setValue(emailSubject, forKey: "Subject")
        viewController!.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    catch {
        print("Error print mulitple images \(error)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make that array a flat object and it should work.

example:

```swift
func share() {
    let activityItems = [
        "Title",
        "Body",
        UIImage(systemName: "keyboard")!,
        UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")!
    ] as [Any]
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    vc.setValue("Testing", forKey: "Subject")
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly now thank you very much!